# Convert .java to .class within a java program

Tags: java, class, compilation, runtime

I have several .java files created during runtime. I want to use those created .java files as classes in my program. How may I do this, without starting the program a second time ? So I want to compile the .java files during runtime and use the new .class files from now on...

Comment: Search for Java Compiler API.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Java Compiler API:

```
public class SimpleCompileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileToCompile = "test" + java.io.File.separator +"MyClass.java";
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);
            if(compilationResult == 0){
               System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
           }else{
               System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
           }
    }
}
```

[Detailed Example with explanation](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Compiler API included in the JDK. [See here.](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/)